# Tweet button count is not increment value

Tags: php, joomla

I have developed a site in joomla and use the tweet button in it and use the following code for that but it is not incrementing the count of tweet:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
// ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: <a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
// ]]></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at whether the JavaScript call to the Twitter API is working with the WebKit inspector. It might be a network condition at your end is affecting access to Twitter's API.

It's also important to note that the large-scale nature of Twitter might mean your Tweets don't affect the 'Tweet count' immediately (or potentially ever in some cases) because of the caching necessary to run such a high demand platform.

Twitter has an FAQ which covers this specific issue here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button/faq#count-api-increment